# Specifying file path for PyPDF2 after using pyInstaller onto a flash drive

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pypdf

I have written a python script that scrapes account numbers from a pdf document and it works great locally. I've used pyinstaller to extract the script into an executable and saved it onto a flash drive. I moved the pdf document into what I thought was the CWD but when I try to run it, my terminal tells me the pdf I'm tyring to open cannot be found.

Eventually I want my client to be able to put the flash drive in, move the newest version of the pdf over to the same directory, and run the script. I need a nudge in the right direction as how to specify the file path for PyPDF2. Here is my code so far.

```
def getDataFromPdf():
acctNumberRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
pdfFile = open('records.pdf', 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
for pageNum in range(0,10):
    page = reader.getPage(pageNum).extractText()
    accounts = acctNumberRegex.findall(page)
    for acct in accounts:
        if acct not in results:
            results.append(acct)
print(len(results))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the file path as an argument into your function.

So:

```py
def getDataFromPdf(filePath):
    acctNumberRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
    pdfFile = open(filePath + 'records.pdf', 'rb')
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
    for pageNum in range(0,10):
        page = reader.getPage(pageNum).extractText()
        accounts = acctNumberRegex.findall(page)
    for acct in accounts:
        if acct not in results:
          results.append(acct)
    print(len(results))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution via r/learnpython

```
SCRIPT_DIR = Path(sys.executable).parent

def getDataFromPdf():
pdf_file = SCRIPT_DIR / 'records.pdf'
print(pdf_file.resolve())
with open(pdf_file.resolve(),'rb') as records:
    acctNumberRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(records)
    for pageNum in range(0,reader.numPages):
        page = reader.getPage(pageNum).extractText()
        accounts = acctNumberRegex.findall(page)
        for acct in accounts:
            if acct not in results:
                results.append(acct)
    print(str(len(results)) + " account numbers pulled from PDF")
```